# How do i catch a SSL/TLS key using python sockets on server side

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-sockets

The client makes a GET request on some websites, like https://www.youtube.com. This request is redirected to my proxy server, which gets all of the data. Then i try to decode('UTF-8') it, but i get error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 8: invalid start byte
```

I suppose this is because of SSL/TLS encryption? But then there is a question ---> **How do I catch an SSL/TLS key using python sockets?**

Comment: Are your trying to implement MITM proxy?

Comment: @AlexeyR. kind of, script is written in python, but the point is to "read as string" https request that client has sent to server.

Comment: I've written something along those lines using `asyncio`. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/synchronizing/mitm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because there are non-ASCII characters and that can't be encoded or decoded.
There is one way to avoid this is to use the `encode()` function.
Let your string is `x`

```
x.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: I suppose this is an answer to error that i got, but still not clear on - how do i make this "non-ASCII" into a real request string that was sent from client? I need to catch SSL/TLS key to decrypt what i got ---- and so, here is the question, how do i catch ssl/tls keys to decrypt what client sends me?

Comment: @BaronRandom You are better off wrapping the socket, and allowing the built-in Python functions to take care of SSL/TLS for you. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket).